# jQuery Coda Slider IE 6,7 Crashing when switching tabs...I hate IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, crash, coda-slider

First off, I would just like to mention my absolute hatred of Internet Explorer and the grief it is causing me.

Okay, so I have am using a Coda slider for a clients website, located at: www.onlineuticacollege.com/david

Here is my  declarations for my Coda Slider.

```
<script src="tabbed-bottom-nav/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="tabbed-bottom-nav/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="tabbed-bottom-nav/js/jquery.coda-slider-2.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
$('div#coda-slider-1').codaSlider({
dynamicArrows: false,
autoHeight: false
});
});
</script>
```

My actual coda slider tabs are way too huge to fit in a post, so here's a link to a pastebin of it: http://pastebin.com/m6f250b9d

But here is the general layout:

```
<div class="panel"><!--Begin Contact Us: panel-->
<div class="panel-wrapper"> 
<h2 class="title">Tab Name</h2>
<p>Some text goes here</p>
<p>More text here.</p>
<div class="panelNavigation">
<a class="xtrig left" href="#4" rel="coda-slider-1" title="Go To Previous">&#171; Previous</a>
<a class="center" href="contact-us/contact.asp" title="Learn More">Learn More</a>
<a class="xtrig right" href="#1" rel="coda-slider-1" title="Go To Next">Next &#187;</a>
</div>
</div>
</div><!--End Contact Us: panel-->
```

Now, all of this *sometimes* works perfectly fine in IE 6,7 except if you switch between the tabs really fast, other times it completely crashes when switching to your first tab...

Any help or suggestions are GREATLY appreciated.

p.s. I hate internet explorer...

[edit] I have gotten it working perfectly on IE 7 somehow...now for IE 6.

Comment: do you want to put a demo up on http://jsbin.com?

Comment: OOH! Never knew about that site, Thanks Russ, I will and I'll edit my post accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is a rather complex problem, I have finally fixed it for both IE 6 and IE 7.

What I ended up doing was just completely remaking the tabs again, which yielded good results with it *mostly* functioning for IE 7, but now it left IE 6 crashing. So, I have found out that all versions of IE do not play well with anything withing the tabs having 100% width or an absolute width that fits the largest amount possible within the tabs (ex. You have a tab that's 600 pixels in width with 5px of padding on each side, you *cannot* have a div that is 550px or larger for the width, this also applies to the height)

In addition if you have multiple divs floating that come close to equaling the width/height - padding/margin when added together it will crash IE 6, but not IE 7.

In the end I had to use tables to arrange two of the different elements. I didn't necessarily want to use tables for it, but it did accomplish the look and the functionality, so I am glad for that.

Hopefully, this can help someone else later on.

Comment: 4 hours of banging my head on the desk, and this thread saved me. Thank you!!

Comment: It was about 6 hours for me, I'm glad this thread helped you!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this has anything to do with it, but in looking at their documentation, elements referenced by IDs don't need the element type declared before them. As a side note, this sounds like a bug in the codaSlider library. The whole point of a JS library is to use one syntax convention, while the library handles cross-browser implementation.

What if you change:

```
$('div#coda-slider-1').codaSlider
```

to

```
$('#coda-slider-1').codaSlider
```

Comment: I actually originally had it with the new markup that you mention and I thought it might by some odd possibility make a difference to IE, but it didn't do anything...I just forgot to switch it back. Thanks for the response! +1

Comment: hmm, didn't see anything else that stuck out. I would try to reduce the page to 2 tabs maybe and test, and keep adding tabs until you can recreate the problem, and then look for anything that may stick out as different in the last added code block?